# The number of emitted/transferred tuples is reset to 0

Tags: apache-storm

I am executing a big task with 10,000,000 records to be processed in my topology.

My first bolt will iterate over those records and submit them record by record to be processed by the next bolt.

When I'm trying to debug the UI statistics, it shows me that after it emits/transfers couple of millions, *it resets the emitted/transferred field to 0* and it actually stops emitting the records! Inside the logs the only message I could see (inside all workers):

```
[INFO] Unable to read additional data from server sessionid 0x1619d6219a00026, likely server has closed socket, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
[INFO] Opening socket connection to server server1/server2:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```